# SonataAdmin - Choice field from non managed entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Imagine a user who is linked to a company:

```
User
    - id
    - username
    - company_id
```

The company list comes from a procedure call (external db), no hands on the related table

```
EXEC getCompanies;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | comp1 |
|  2 | comp2 |
|  3 | comp3 |
+----+-------+
```

How would you integrate this to allow SonataAdmin to render a proper input selection for company in User editition, and display the company name in User list ?

Do you know where I could find some examples about this particular case ?

---

I did a custom `company` field type which fetchs his values from the procedure call, but I'm not sure it's the best idea and I'm not able to display the comany name in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `choice` type and if there are too many companies to display, you can use [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle) with Select2 library to have filtering select widget.

Comment: The number of item is not a problem and I'm already extending `choice` type. The problem is more about fetching the values from a procedure call and displaying the label in the list. Thank for [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) I didn't know it, seems very good.

Comment: You could write a method that preloads company entity list to the user inside the `UserManager` and inject that `UserManager` into your `Admin`. Your could also register Doctrine listener that loads the list automatically after each onLoad event (then no need to inject into Admin).